# Error to create view use ifnull function in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select g.id, ifnull(s.count, 0)
from t_goods g
left join v_stock s on g.id = s.id
```

This sql works well, and then I create a view:

```
create or drop view v_goods_stock as
select g.id, ifnull(s.count, 0)
from t_goods g
left join v_stock s on g.id = s.id
```

I get the error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

My mysql version is 5.5.

I try to remove the ifnull function like this

```
create or drop view v_goods_stock as select g.id id, s.count c from t_goods g left join v_stock s on g.id = s.id
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is pretty simple, and has nothing to do with `IFNULL()`: MySQL does not recognize the syntax `CREATE OR DROP VIEW`. ([Here's the syntax reference for `CREATE VIEW`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html))

Remove the words `OR DROP`, or replace it with `OR REPLACE` if you need this statement to work when the view already exists.

Answer (score 2):

You must give a column name to the calculated value:

```
create or replace view v_goods_stock as
select g.id, ifnull(s.count, 0) as count
from t_goods g  
left join v_stock s on g.id = s.id
```

The default column name is the expression itself `ifnull(s.count, 0)`, which is not a valid name (contains brackets, commas, etc)